# Is it possible to add a discussion tag?

Tags: discussion, scope, tags

I have some pretty good thought experiments that I would like to share with the physics community here (I'm sure others have them too), but I can't find a way to phrase them as questions.

I've read through the rules, and it specifically says "Is your question about physics? We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.", so I can't ask it on the forum itself...

Also, Meta is only for discussing the website itself, such as format issues, bugs, and such.

Can we add a tag for discussion, so that people like me, who are interested in hearing other people's ideas, can do so?

Comment: Also, as a side note, does anyone else see this idea as helpful as well?

Comment: [Stack Exchange is not a discussion forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums).

Comment: Related: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6985/ , https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9887/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, what you suggest is not what this site was designed for. If you want to have a discussion, take it to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar) or to some other webpage. Cheers!

Comment: Oops... Forgot about that option. Can you help me close this question? (I also can't seem to accept your answer, sorry)

Comment: You can delete your own questions.

Comment: @NiamhO'SS [You can't delete questions with upvoted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) (see also [the help center](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions)). But why would you need to? Shreyas asked a reasonable question (to which the answer is No), people disagreed that it's a good idea, and there's now a reasonable answer.