# Can I State a Thought About Physics and Ask for Comments

Tags: discussion

I have what I think is an insight, based on a set theoretic analysis of the Riemann integral, regarding whether or not there are any physical variables that really are continuous, vs. discrete. For instance, in QM, energy is quantized but position and time are not yet known to be quantized. However, I think that a set theoretic analysis of integration may indicate that for integrals to work for variables like position, then position probably is quantized. It is not really a question but is more of an analysis. Is it OK to briefly state it and ask if people think it makes sense and has any value?

I do not have a full blown paper to publish, nor a typical question. I just want to get feedback on a thought that I had that I can state clearly and briefly. If not here, then where could I do that? I am hoping here.

Thanks,

David

Comment: possible duplicate: [Is it possible to add a discussion tag?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10516/84967).

Comment: Please read the answers under [I believe I have solved a famous open problem. How do I convince people in the field that I am not a crank?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/18491/) before you interact with any professionals, particularly the one by Kaveh.

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like the kind of thing that would be off topic under [our policy on non-mainstream physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4538/is-non-mainstream-physics-appropriate-for-this-site).

What you could do is go to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71) and see if anyone might be interested in giving you feedback on your idea.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the place for what you have in mind, neither for you nor for the users of the site.  The site is set up to answer questions rather than discussions, and it sounds like you want to have a discussion.  Web chats work well between people with lots in common, but discussions - especially through a website - on very novel topics are often complicated by the lack of familiarity with the topic.  Presumably few people will be able to understand what you have in mind, the technical terms you use might have slightly different accepted meanings for different participants, and all it takes is a simple typo to stop the momentum of the discussion.

I would recommend that you write some sort of draft to sort out your ideas in a logical manner, and then contact a professional for a live meeting.  There is only so much you can do by writing, and interacting in person with someone is oftentimes the best way to clarify some points and get feedback, i.e. basically overcome all the challenges mentioned above. The difficulty will be finding someone who will listen to you.

Answer (score -4):

> Can I State a Thought About Physics and Ask for Comments

No, but you could state your case and then ask a pointed question about it.

> I have what I think is an insight, based on a set theoretic analysis of the Riemann integral, regarding whether or not there are any physical variables that really are continuous, vs. discrete. For instance, in QM, energy is quantized but position and time are not yet known to be quantized.

Energy isn't really quantized, in that the photon has an E=hf wave nature, and it can have any frequency and therefore any energy you like. However the photon is quantized, since h applies to all photons.

> However, I think that a set theoretic analysis of integration may indicate that for integrals to work for variables like position, then position probably is quantized.

As far as we know that photon doesn't approach you in steps.

> It is not really a question but is more of an analysis. Is it OK to briefly state it and ask if people think it makes sense and has any value?

Not really. Like I said you could state your case and then ask a pointed question about it.

> I do not have a full blown paper to publish, nor a typical question. I just want to get feedback on a thought that I had that I can state clearly and briefly. If not here, then where could I do that? I am hoping here.

I think you should try here and see how you get on. I wouldn't try chat if I were you.